# Using Pandas functions instead of for loops to find top three items in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, part of it is shown in this picture(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKJ8G.png).
So I need to find the sum of the populations(using 2010 census) of the 3 most populated counties in every state and find the top 3 states having the highest sum.
I am new to pandas so I used loops and conditionals to accomplish the task
This is the code I wrote:

```
def answer_six():
    top1=["nil",0]
    top2=["nil",0]
    top3=["nil",0]
    for item in census_df['STNAME']:
        s_sum=census_df[census_df['STNAME'] == item].nlargest(3, ['CENSUS2010POP'])['CENSUS2010POP'].sum()
        if top1[1]==0:
            top1=[item,s_sum]
        if s_sum>top1[1]:
            top3=top2
            top2=top1
            top1=[item,s_sum]
        if s_sum<top1[1] and s_sum>top2[1]:
            top3=top2
            top2=[item,s_sum]
        if s_sum<top2[1] and s_sum>top3[1]:
            top3=[item,s_sum]
    ans=[top1[0],top2[0],top3[0]]
    return ans
```

Running this code takes approximately 15 seconds to get the answer. Is there any better way using pandas dataframe function like sum(), max(), etc.

Comment: Groupby county, then sum population, then sort descending, and call ```head(3)```. Similar approach for state.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from a [Code Review discussion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151530/finding-the-states-with-the-three-most-populous-counties/151807), this will work:

```
census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50].groupby(
    'STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].apply(
    lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum()).nlargest(
    3).index.values.tolist()
```